# Difficulty during self-studying unique set proofs

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning

I have been following Velleman's How to prove it and working through it on my own. I am working full time now so I can only study after work without any other help. It's been going fairly ok until I started studying existence and uniqueness proof for sets.

I simply cannot grasp the strategy at all. I have the solution to every problem, but every problem I have encountered involves assuming one set to be identical to another, numerous comments on this site mentioned that knowing what to assume comes with practise, but this is the problem - every single problem I come across in this book starts off impossible and I cannot make any progress that grants me experience. The book also offers no strategy at all apart from noting the three equivalent forms of ext. and uniq. proof (in fact, not even any useful example on proving such sets except a pretty easy one).

I am also suffering huge anxiety from this; at one point I was stuck at a question for a month (I have since given it up), and despite asking for help on this forum, I cannot even fully understand the solutions offered. I am so anxious that at one point I found myself panting heavily even when I merely set sight on a problem.

So may I ask for help on the following please:

1. Good reference book with abundant exercises + solutions on existence and uniqueness proof on sets
2. How do I cope with the anxiety?
3. Good strategy to solving existence and uniqueness proofs/reference that discusses such matters

Thank you so much!

Comment: Concerning the anxiety, I am not a psychologist/psychiatrist, so I cannot offer you any expert advice, but please keep in mind that it *is not* that important! Suppose you never pick it up? Will your life end? No. Will you be some big laughingstock? No. You already are better at math than 90%+ of the population. Will it cut off career paths? Very, very few. Does it mean you are stupid? Obviously not. Fantastically intelligent people abound who have almost no ability with higher math. So keep things in perspective. It isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for your kind advise; I guess I am anxious because ultimately I want to enter the academia of philosophy, and to do that I need a solid understanding of meta-logic - which set theory is a crucial component. But if I can't even tackle this, this means 1) I am likely not even competent enough to apply for postgraduate, 2) even if I am admitted it is likely I will not survive given I have always been a slow learner and courses are likely to proceed quickly

Comment: Even if you don't succeed at that (and I have no reason to believe that you will not - but let's just examine the worst case), it doesn't mean you can't be happy. My dreams didn't come true, but i've found a fulfilling career along a different path. Your point (1) is completely wrong. Most academics have a poor grasp of meta-logic, including most mathematicians - it isn't necessary for their work. Your point (2) is more of an issue, and may require a less-traditional path - taking fewer courses and more time, but such paths are available.